# Decimal^ Specified Cast Invalid calling ToString()

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, decimal

I have a class defined as:

```
    public ref class MyParameters
    {
    private:
        property Decimal^ tickValue;
    public:
        MyParameters(Decimal^ tickValue){
              this->tickValue = tickValue;
          }
        std::string GetTickValue();

   };


    std::string MyParameters::GetTickValue()
    {
        String^ test = this->tickValue->ToString(); <--Invalid Cast here
        return marshal_as<std::string>(test);
    }
```

If I breakpoint on that line and paste `this->tickValue->ToString()` into the quick watch it works fine!

I did notice that my Constructor signature was changed to `MyParameters(ValueType^ tickValue)`??

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure this is exactly the code you have, especially since I had to a syntax error in it? What is the stack trace of the exception? Are you sure you're passing a `decimal` to the constructor?

Comment: `System::Decimal` is a value-type, not a reference-type. Change all `Decimal^` to `Decimal` unless there's a reason you actually want boxing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no concept of “typed reference to value type” in .Net.* And since `Decimal^` is exactly that, it's not possible to compile that properly. As you noticed, what the compiler does is to instead make the parameter `ValueType^`, which is the closest thing to `Decimal^` in the .Net type system. It also adds some metadata, so that when you call the constructor from C++/CLI, only boxed `Decimal` can be passed to it.

But other languages don't understand that metadata, all they see is `ValueType`. That means that you can call the constructor from, say, C# like this and it works fine:

```
new MyParameters(42)
```

Notice that I passed in an `int`, not `decimal`. And this `int` is saved in the `tickValue` field (which is actually also `ValueType^`). And only when trying to actually use its value as `Decimal^`, you get `InvalidCastException`.

The easiest way to fix this is not to use references to value types. That is, instead of `Decimal^`, use just `Decimal` and everything should work fine.

* Strictly speaking, there is `TypedReference`, but that's not meant for normal use.